# std::enable_if with multiple or-conditions

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I am struggling to find the correct syntax for allowing multiple OR'ed `std::enable_if` conditions for my template functions.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
using Foo = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>>;

template <typename T>
using Bar = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, float>>;

// Fine - accepts only ints
template <typename T, typename = Foo<T>>
void FooIt(T t) {}

// Fine - accepts only floats
template <typename T, typename = Bar<T>>
void BarIt(T t) {}

template <typename T,
          // This does not work
          typename = std::enable_if_t<Bar<T>::value || Foo<T>::value>>
void FooOrBarIt(T t) {}

int main() {
  FooIt(1);
  BarIt(1.0f);

  // FooIt(1.0f);  // OK - No float version of FooIt
  // BarIt(1);     // OK - No int version of BarIt

  // Not OK - Both fails to compile
  // FooOrBarIt(1);
  // FooOrBarIt(1.0f);
}
```

I want the `FooOrBarIt` function to accept both `int`s and `float`s but nothing else by combining the previous `Foo` and `Bar` conditions.

Note that I want to avoid changing the previous conditions, I want to combine them as is. Anything C++17 is fine.

The current code fails with compile errors like:

```
candidate template ignored: requirement 'std::is_same_v<int, float>' was not satisfied [with T = int]
```

in clang.

Comment: When `T` is an `int`, `Foo<T>` is `void` and doesn't have a `::value` member.

Comment: Yes, the current line there is just one of many failed attempts which were all broken if different ways.

Comment: Is it at all possible for you to upgrade to C++20 and do this with concepts?

Comment: Also might be worth remarking that the "working" version isn't quite as restrictive as you might want. `FooIt<double, void>(1.0);` compiles just fine, for example. So does `FooIt<std::string, std::string>("Hello world");`.

Comment: I am happy to see a C++20 solution, but it's not available in the code base I am working on at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to use `enable_if_t` inside of `enable_if_t`, which is not what you need.  You need to use `is_same_v` inside of 1 `enable_if_t`, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T,float> || std::is_same_v<T,int>>>
```

So adjust your `using` statements accordingly, eg:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool Is_Int = std::is_same_v<T, int>;

template <typename T>
using Enable_If_Int = std::enable_if_t<Is_Int<T>>;

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool Is_Float = std::is_same_v<T, float>;

template <typename T>
using Enable_If_Float = std::enable_if_t<Is_Float<T>>;

// Fine - accepts only ints
template <typename T, typename = Enable_If_Int<T>>
void FooIt(T t) {}

// Fine - accepts only floats
template <typename T, typename = Enable_If_Float<T>>
void BarIt(T t) {}

template <typename T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<Is_Float<T> || Is_Int<T>>>
void FooOrBarIt(T t) {}

int main() {
    FooIt(1);
    BarIt(1.0f);

    // FooIt(1.0f);  // OK - No float version of FooIt
    // BarIt(1);     // OK - No int version of BarIt

    // OK - Both compile fine
    FooOrBarIt(1);
    FooOrBarIt(1.0f);
}
```

[Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1KrsfcGEG)

Comment: Thanks, I guess it's not possible to use Foo and Bar directly as I initially thought - but this seem to be the easiest way with only minor changes to my original conditions.

Answer (score 2):

SFINAE doesn’t work quiet as simply with logical operators. You should look to use [`std::disjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction) and its counterpart `std::conjunction` to combine logical tests for SFINAE. These where introduced with C++17, so you should be able to use them with the setup you have.

Comment: But that would still have to be a disjunction over `std::is_same<T, int>` and `std::is_same<T, float>`, right? I don't see that you'd be able to actually use `Foo` and `Bar` for this.

Comment: My understanding is that it relates to the use of the || operator, so both arguments need to compile. But with the std::disjunction, it would only need to compile (or fail a substitution) as it passes them down the “tree”, ultimately ending with a type, or a failed substitution.

Comment: Yes but what I'm saying is that the type arguments passed to `disjunction` need to have `value` members, which `Foo<T>` and `Bar<T>` don't. So we can't construct a disjunction like `std::disjunction<Foo<T>, Bar<T>>`, we have to go back to `is_same`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work with `is_same`, but as Nathan said I have not found a way to use `Foo` and `Bar` directly with `std::disjunction` so it would require some code duplication in my current project, which I would like to avoid if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your `||` operator works on `bool` types.

The `bool` types you are looking for already exist in your code.  `std::is_same_v` is always a `bool.`

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<
           std::is_same_v<T,int> || std::is_same_v<T,float>
         >>* = nullptr
```

Consider that an expression containing **both** `Foo<T>` and `Bar<T>` can never be well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing cargo-cult SFINAE.  By this, I mean you are using SFINAE patterns to pull off what you need, and not understanding why you are doing those patterns.

This usually isn't all that bad.  SFINAE is sort of insane, as an accidental feature that leaked into the language and gave us Turing-complete overload resolution.  I mean, last I checked, the fact it worked with template class specialization isn't actually in the standard.

So following existing patterns to make it look reasonable is a good plan.

When you want to do something new, however, you have to understand what is actually going on.

```
template <typename T>
using Foo = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>>;
```

this is a template alias that results in the type `void` if `T` passes the test, and in a substitution failure if `T` fails the test.

```
// Fine - accepts only ints
template <typename T, typename = Foo<T>>
void FooIt(T t) {}
```

your comment is a bit wrong.  `FooIt<double, void>` works fine here.

What is going on here is that your default type argument produces a substitution failure if `T` is not an `int`.  If `T` is an `int`, the default value for the 2nd type argument is `void`.

```
template <typename T,
      // This does not work
      typename = std::enable_if_t<Bar<T>::value ||  Foo<T>::value>>
void FooOrBarIt(T t) {}
```

of course it doesn't.

There is no `::value` on the type `void`.  `Bar<T>` is either `void` or a substitution failure, and the same for `Foo<T>`.

Neither supports `::value`.  So you get an error.

Your `Foo<T>` and `Bar<T>` are not a great pattern.  But you stated you want to keep them.

So what I'd start with is this:

```
template<class T, template<class>class Z, class=void, template<class>class...Zs>
struct test{};
template<class T, template<class>class Z>
struct test<T,Z,Z<T>>{
  using type=void;
};
template<class T,
  template<class>class Z0,
  template<class>class Z1, 
  template<class>class...Zs
>
struct test<T, Z0, Z0<T>, Z1, Zs...>:
  test<T, Z1, void, Zs...>
{};
template<class T, template<class>class Z0, template<class>class...Zs>
using test_t = typename test<T, Z0, void, Zs...>::type;
```

now `test_t` can be used to fuze your traits.

```
template <typename T,
      typename = test_t<T, Bar, Foo>>
void FooOrBarIt(T t) {}
```

in a way you are familiar with.

## Digression

Note that this style of SFINAE has problems where you can't use it to dispatch between two overloads of `FooOrBarIt`.  Ie,

```
template<class T, class=Bar<T>>
void bob(T) {}
template<class T, class=Foo<T>>
void bob(T) {}
```

this results in an overload resolution error.

Another cargo-cult pattern:

```
template<class T>
using Bar = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T,int>, bool>;
template<class T>
using Foo = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T,double>, bool>;

template<class T, Bar<T> =true>
void bob(T) {}
template<class T, Foo<T> =true>
void bob(T) {}
```

looks slightly different, but permits the two `bob` overloads above to work.

For that variant, you'd have to change how you joined them:

```
template<Ts...>
using AllTraits = bool;

template <typename T,
      AllTraits<Foo<T>, Bar<T>> = true>
void FooOrBarIt(T t) {}
```

note that the `=true` in this particular cargo cult version is not a test; `=false` would produce the exact same results.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of providing a contrast, a C++20 version:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
concept Foo = std::is_same_v<T, int>;

template<typename T>
concept Bar = std::is_same_v<T, float>;

template<typename T>
concept FooOrBar = Foo<T> || Bar<T>;

template<Foo T>
void FooIt(T) { }

template<Bar T>
void BarIt(T) { }

template<FooOrBar T>
void FooOrBarIt(T) { }

int main() {
  FooIt(1); // OK
  BarIt(1.0f); // OK
  
  // FooIt(1.0f);  // OK - No float version of FooIt
  // BarIt(1);     // OK - No int version of BarIt


  FooOrBarIt(1); // OK
  FooOrBarIt(1.0f); // OK
  // FooOrBarIt(1.0); // No double version of FooOrBarIt
}
```

Concepts are a lot easier to combine in this fashion.